# Android - MediaPlayer display volume levels graphically

Tags: java, android, media-player, volume

I'm using MediaPlayer to play a song I have in my raw folder

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song1;);
mPlayer.start();
```

Is there a way I can visually see the volume levels as the song is playing? So something like this, but it can be very basic so I can tell when the song is loud or not

[image]

Comment: Did you try using `setVolume()` method?

Answer (score 0):

It is actualy depend upon how much steps You want

Let's suppose you want maximum volume of 100 steps

`int maxVolume = 100;`

then you can set to setVolume any value (0-99) in range try this:

```
 `float volume = (float)(Math.volume(maxVolume - currVolume)/Math.volume(maxVolume));`
```

`yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1-volume);`